# Apache LogFormat and removing a header

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I have a script that creates the header:

```
X-User-ID: 1234
```

I would like to log the value, but ideally not send it back to the client.

The logging can be done with:

```
LogFormat "... %{X-User-ID}o ..." inc_ref
```

But this does not work when I add:

```
Header unset "X-User-ID"
```

Is there a way to unset the header, but still log the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mp_de, @covener, and @diego, the answer is:

```
Header always note "X-User-ID" "User-ID"
Header always unset "X-User-ID"

LogFormat "... %{User-ID}n ..." inc_ref
```

Because it needs to be copied in to a `note` first, as the `unset` header value is not available to LogFormat.

And because `mod_proxy_fcgi` adds response headers to `r->err_headers_out` so mod `mod_headers` needs to use `always` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but the same question over at [Header unset seems not to work with apache 2.4.10 and php-fpm](https://serverfault.com/questions/646773/header-unset-seems-not-to-work-with-apache-2-4-10-and-php-fpm).

Even if you use `Header [always] note ...`, logging that noted value with `%{VARNAME}n` does not work if you use `Header [always] unset ...`.

Might be a bug in Apache.

Comment: Thanks @mp_de, the last answer there gave me the answer I needed... use "Header always note" (always needed for mod_proxy_fcgi), and "Header always unset".